# SharePoint Modal and Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, iframe, datatables

I was wondering if there is a way to load additional scripts in the iFrame after using the SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog function?

My scenario is I'm currently loading a modal (which is in a iFrame) using this function to display list items (these items can be in multiple lists but not important at this point).  I want to display this data in a table format using the jQuery Datatables library.  My problem is I can't reference the files normally because the data is shown in an iFrame so can I somehow load the library when rendering the modal?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get this working.  A simple example is to have your table HTML in a script block (like below).

```
<script type="text/html" id="tableId">
    <div id="divTable">
        <table id="table" class="display dataTable order-column" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        </table>
    </div>
</script>
```

You can then call the SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog function using "tableId" to show the HTML inside the script block.  You can actually manipulate everything inside the modal as normal so calling

```
$('#table').DataTable();
```

Actually works.  You can then use DataTables as normal.